# Property doesn't update after firing redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, use-effect

After hours I have to ask for help, my useEffect doesn't always work on reduxs dispatching action.

```
const ScreenA = { currentItem, updatedItem } => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if (currentItem.id === updatedItem.id) { // Do stuff } 
    }, [updatedItem]) // XX Is not changing 

... // do stuf

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        console.log("AAABB ScreenA.mapStateToProps updatedItem: ", state.updatedItem) // XX I receive new updated id!! but it doesn't change the prop.updatedItem for ScreenA and useEffect is not calling. 
        return {
            updatedItem: state.updatedItem,
        }
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FeedScreen)
}
```

**My Reducer**
Update

```
const initialState = {
    updatedItem: undefined,
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ITEM_CHANGED:
            console.log("AAABB reducer.addChangedItem.ITEM_CHANGED: " + action.t) // Is printing after every dispatch call

            return {
                ...state,
                updatedItem: action.updatedItem,
            }

            // I tried also with 
            return {  
                updatedItem: action.updatedItem,
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Strange was that it works if I dispatch change action from ScreenB to ScreenA but not between ScreenC to ScreenA. (It was the same way how I dispatch the action.

Comment: need to see your reducer, it's probably a mutation issue

Comment: @JoeLloyd is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Spread out your updated item as well

Since your updated item is an object perhaps that causes a mutation. Seems unlikely but this are the issues you face when not using flat data. also generally you have a `type` and a `payload` (not updated item) on your action in redux.

```
return {
  ...state,
  updatedItem: {...action.updatedItem},
}
```

If this doesn't work then probably something in your useEffect is broken, you need to log inside there and show results.

Comment: Wow, it's working, I need more tests, but it looks like I have a new hero for today, thank you.

Comment: @A.Amini no problem, just some advice about updating "deep" objects inside your state. You should avoid this and try to keep data as flat as possible to avoid these kinds of issue.